# Android Studio shows red exclamation at drawable attribute

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

In layout XML files, the red exclamation mark is displayed left of `@drawable` references. Almost all `drawable`s have this mark:

[image]

The content of `shape_detail_btn_border.xml` is as below. It is a group of shapes and does not have any broken image resource:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
    <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/bapul_color_d5d5d5"/>
</shape>
```

I hover the mouse on the mark and nothing shows up. what does this mean?

Note that the Android Studio version is 1.4 (AI-141.2288178), currently the most recent version. And, there's **no problem** to build and run the app at all.

Comment: I believe that this is a bug with the 1.4 version of AS - we had this same issue that just started happening.

Comment: Hey, Have you created the color String in color.xml for bapul_color_d5d5d5 in Studio ?

Comment: @RajanBhavsar // of course. there's no problem to build and run the app.

Comment: Please refer the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33032123/unknown-exclamatory-symbol-in-the-xml-file

Answer (score 60, accepted):

In short, **it's not an error from the code.** It tells that "Android Studio failed to display the thumbnail of the given drawable."

Thanks @Ramz for finding an answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/33032200/361100. I'll leave this post because this question is more descriptive than the linked one.

Answer (score 0):

The red exclamation point also appears in Java source files where a drawable is referenced. It can be eliminated by adding an on-demand static import for R.drawable. For example:

```
import static com.mycompany.myapp.R.drawable.*;
```